# Making Java I / O and change the file to split in java

Tags: java, io, split, bufferedreader

I'm making a project where using java I / O

I have a file with the following data:

> 170631|0645|    |002014     |      0713056699|000000278500
> 155414|0606|    |002014     |      0913042385|000001220000
> 000002|0000|0000|00000000000|0000000000000000|000000299512

and the output I want is as follows:

> 170631
>
> 0645
>
> 002014

file so that the data will be decreased down
and this is my source code:

```
public class Tes {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    File file;
    BufferedReader br =null;
    FileOutputStream fop = null;
    try {
        String content = "";
        String s;
        file = new File("E:/split/OUT/Berhasil.RPT");
        fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:/split/11072014/01434.RPT"));
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            for (String retVal : s.split("\\|")) {
                
                String data = content.concat(retVal);
                System.out.println(data.trim());        
                byte[] buffer = data.getBytes();
                fop.write(buffer);
                fop.flush();
                fop.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I want is to generate output as above from the data that has been entered

File Input -> Split -> File Output

thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, what's your question again? Specifically, what problems are you having with your code?

Comment: ... and rather than writing directly with a FileOutputStream, why not use a Stream geared towards use of Strings such as by wrapping your FileOutputStream with a PrintStream?

Comment: ohh I'm sorry maybe my english is not good, 
I just want to change that in the input file with BufferedReader, when the file was already in. I want to change the split removes the "|" with ("\ \ |"), if it is converted files will be saved back to the Berhasil.txt name. thanks

Comment: @MadBoy why do you need to read rtp extension?

Comment: I have a file with format (. RPT) and the contents as I put on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to mention what problem are you facing. Just by looking at the code it seems like you are closing the fop(FileOutputStream) every time you are looping while writing the split line. The outputStream should be closed once you have written everything, outside the while loop.

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileReadWrite {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileReader inputFileReader = new FileReader(new File("E:/split/11072014/01434.RPT"));
        FileWriter outputFileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("E:/split/11072014/Berhasil.RPT"));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputFileReader);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputFileWriter);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            for (String splitItem : line.split("|")) {
                bufferedWriter.write(splitItem + "\n");
            }
        }
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Ohh sorry, I still can not understand the Java I / O. 
Could you give an explanation? what should I change in my source code. thanks

Comment: I tried it, and it's really going well, but there is one thing in the regex "|" character will be decreased to make the letters one by one instead of by restriction, so I change again with "\ \ |", thank you very much for help, it will be well when applied to the framework. 
:)